# Can I use a class insted of an instance of a class for better readability?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a situation where i can make an object as a class:

```
class BenjaminFranklin(Cat):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ishungry = False
        self.legs = 4
        self.name_eng = 'Benjamin Franklin'
```

or an instance of a class:

```
benjamin_franklin = Cat()
benjamin_franklin.ishungry = False
benjamin_franklin.legs = 4
benjamin_franklin.name_eng = 'Benjamin Franklin'
```

The 'Correct' options seems to be using an instance of a class because there is no group of cats with the name "Benjamin Franklin"; there is only one and only cat. But it is much less readable, especially when using long names.

Tell me please:

- "You can use class in this case for better readability, because..."
- "The only correct option is to use an instance, because..."
- Something else

Thanks

Comment: In what way is an instance of a class less readable?

Comment: Does the `Cat` class contain the `ishungry`, `legs` and `name_eng` attributes? If yes then you should *definitely* use an instance, if not then it depends. Usually: if you create a subclass only to create an instance you probably don't need the subclass at all.

Comment: It's less readable because `Cat.__init__` is poorly defined; at the very least, you should be able to pass arguments to `__init__` (`Cat(False, 4, "Benjamin Franklin")`).

Comment: Are the attributes `ishungry`, `legs` and `name_eng` on the `Cat` object or were they added to `BenjaminFranklin` only?

Comment: The Singleton design pattern gets tossed around, but primarily in languages where you have no choice but to define a class and create an instance of it. Python has no such restriction; a class with only a single instance should probably just be a module instead.

Comment: @blhsing when it an object with a long name and a lot of attributes. like phra_borom_maha_ratcha_wang = Cat(*add 30 attributes*)

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta yes it does (and defaults are different). Thank you for an answer.

Comment: @chepner thank you for an answer

Comment: @Woody1193 they are attributes of the Cat, but by default they are different (let's say - 0 legs)

Comment: @chepner thank you for an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than building `benjamin_franklin` the way you are, I would change your  `Cat` constructor so it can take the arguments necessary to properly build out the object. Then, you could do something like `benjamin_franklin = Cat('Benjamin Franklin')` which would be much more readable. Such a constructor would look like:

```
def __init__(self, name_eng, is_hungry = False, legs = 4):
    self.ishungry = is_hungry
    self.legs = legs
    self.name_eng = name_eng
```

However, if that is not an option, you could embed your code into a factory method:

```
def BenjaminFranklin():
    benjamin_franklin = Cat()
    benjamin_franklin.ishungry = False
    benjamin_franklin.legs = 4
    benjamin_franklin.name_eng = 'Benjamin Franklin'
    return benjamin_franklin
```

If you have an object with many attributes on it, you could also try encapsulating the object into sub-objects and passing those in on your constructor. For instance, suppose your `Cat` had an identity with a `name_eng` and `name_cha`:

```
 class Identity:

     def __init__(self, name_eng, name_cha):
         self.name_eng = name_eng
         self.name_cha = name_cha


 class Cat:

     def __init__(self, id, ishungry = False, legs = 4):
         self.identity = id
         self.is_hungry = ishungry
         self.legs = legs
```

which you could initialize like this:

```
benjamin_franklin = Cat(Identity('Benjamin Franklin', '猫'))
```

this is somewhat more verbose but it means that you can spread out your construction over several objects (and maybe create some constant objects that are the same over your most instantiations of your class).

Comment: Fixing `Cat` is far more important then the wrapper to work around its shortcomings.

Comment: @chepner I agree. However, it could be that he can't change the implementation of `Cat` for some reason. Rather than assume his situation, I would like to offer an approach that could solve his immediate problem while providing the advice to do it the right way

Comment: Im just saying, lead with fixing `Cat`. Don't assume it's some horribly broken 3rd-party client that must be used no matter the cost; it's just as likely the OP wrote `Cat` as well.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, factory is an interesting option (if no other options)

Answer (score 3):

I assume, Benjamin Franklin is a single Cat. Therefore it should be an instance of the class cat.

One way you could do this would be:

```
class Cat:
   def __init__(self, name_eng, is_hungry=False, legs=4):
        self.ishungry = is_hungry
        self.legs = legs
        self.name_eng = name_eng
```

And then initialize your instance by:

```
benjamin_franklin = Cat("Benjamin Franklin") # is_hungry and legs do not to be passed, as they have the values you asked for defined as default
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. For an example that i posted that seem reasonable. But what if the situation looks like: phra_borom_maha_ratcha_wang = Cat("Phra Borom Maha Ratcha Wang", True, "black", 3, ...30 more attributes...). What will be a good solution?

Comment: Ah, so you have many attributes on your class and passing them all to a constructor would be difficult.

Comment: E.g. you could put that data in a dictionary and give Cat a classmethod, that returns an instance of a Cat built from a dict. Does you cat get any methods as well? If not you are probably better of just using a dict to store your cats properties (could also be saved to a json file for example).

Answer (score 0):

Neither option feels right. The name `BenjaminFranklin` suggests that this is an instance of something. However, the question is why `no_legs`, `is_hungry` etc are specific to Benjamin Franklin, and not to all cats. It seems that those attributes should me moved up to the parent `Cat` class, and Benjamin Franklin should be an instance of it.

Moreover, if only benjamin franklin has a `num_legs` variable, what does he do with it? There is no added function that uses the new fields. In that sense, this seems more like a dict, or a `namedtuple` than an instance of a class.

However, it's not possible to tell what the best way is without seeing the functionality of the `Cat` class, and how you use the extra attributes of benjamin franklin.

Comment: If you look at his instantiation of `benjamin_franklin` as an object, you can see that `Cat` has all the attributes necessary to properly build the object. Therefore, this seems like a readability question or a question on which arguments should be required on `__init__`

Comment: @Woody1193: `Cat` has none of these attributes

Comment: Technically, the instance has the attributes, not `Cat` or the subclass. However, there's no reason why `Cat.__init__` can't set them, which is the crux of the problem.

Comment: @blue_note He sets all the attributes on `benjamin_franklin` after constructing it as a `Cat` object. I understand that, by setting them, he adds them as attributes on the object but that still implies that they're there. Maybe clarification is needed?

Comment: @chepner: that's the whole idea of my answer. If the instance has unique attributes, and it never uses them, it's rather a dict than a class. They should be moved up to cat

Comment: Thank you for an answer. A Cat class has all of the attributes, for example benjamin_franklin.ishungry = True
benjamin_franklin.legs = 0
benjamin_franklin.name_eng = 'Cat'